# DJI SDK Android - unwanted yaw motion on GoToAction in time line mission

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to develop a mobile application using DJI Mobile Android SDK. The goal of the application is navigate a Mavic 2 Pro to a target GPS coordinates and automatically center a camera on a vehicle and take a snapshot. After taking off and flying to target altitude a new tracking mission in spotlight mode is called to find an object and center a camera on it.

The first process goes normally after an aircraft is turned on and the mobile application runs the missions. The aircraft is landed manually.

The second trial with the mobile application goes wrong. There is an additional yaw motion that is not in time line mission. I have missed some cleaning method that reset the aircraft to an initial clean state probably.

How to setup the aircraft to a clean state before the application starts the missions please?

I don't understand why there is a yaw 45° motion in a simple
time line mission:

```
missionControl.scheduleElement(new TakeOffAction());
missionControl.scheduleElement(new GoToAction(2.0f));
missionControl.startTimeline();
```

Why the aircraft yaw 45° after the takeoff while it is lifting to target
altitude? It's to see https://youtu.be/-gCWFXou-WI

Comment: see the reproduceable post in the help center.  Are you sure you don't have compass interference? and all other part is running correctly?

Comment: Thank you. The same behavior I can reproduce in an Assistant simulator. I'll investigate it more and bring back details.

Answer (score 0):

You never share any other code. so below is my list of guess/checklist for a possible solution.

**First**, clear all other code, e.g disable drone yaw following or any other possible routing with the keyword of **tracking/following** etc from both code and remote controller screen

The easiest way to check if it caused by this is to call

```
elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(homeLatitude+0.00001, homeLongitude+0.00001), 5));
elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(homeLatitude-0.00001, homeLongitude-0.00001), 5));
```

if the camera still follows you while at a multiple location. Then sth at tracking is bothering you. If follow it could be caused by home lock also

**Secondly**, GoToAction never mentions about the orientation but only 3D position. Theoretically, they can do anything they want. **so check API for all orientation method/setting** e.g

Use **setFlightOrientationMode** to set course lock  or home lock to get your desired behavior.

```
method setFlightOrientationMode
void setFlightOrientationMode(@NonNull FlightOrientationMode type,
                                                 @Nullable CompletionCallback callback)
Package:    dji.sdk.flightcontroller
SDK Key:    FlightControllerKey.ORIENTATION_MODE
Description:
Sets the aircraft flight orientation relative to the Aircraft Heading, Course Lock, or Home Lock. See the Flight Controller User Guide for more information about flight orientation.
```

**Last** I assume you removed all other possible following modes and it is still not behave according to your wish.

The api given is

```
GoToAction(LocationCoordinate2D coordinate)

GoToAction(float altitude)
float altitude  Target altitude in meters.

GoToAction(LocationCoordinate2D coordinate, float altitude)
```

If the direct setting altitude has an issue. Can you try the full command to determine it is a bug in the source code or it is sth else

```
double homeLatitude = get your start gps lat;
double homeLongitude = get your start gps long;
elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), 2));
```

If you are sure that you have no other routing that bothers the drone, and both GoToAction(float altitude) and GoToAction(LocationCoordinate2D coordinate, float altitude) has the same yaw problem. open a ticket in dev@dji.com.

Personally, I don't think it is DJI`s issue.  Because you never post the full code so I have no idea what you have done or you haven't have done but should have done.  So good luck in finding the solution to your unwanted behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive solution list.
I have found out that the yaw motion **doesn't** appear when the aircraft is turned off and on again. It seems that the aircraft remembers something from previous tracking mission. I will complete the origin question with more details.